# "No class def found" error when using OpenAM SDK via Kotin

Tags: java, kotlin, openam

I am trying to use OpenAM SDK for some task. When using any of SDK classes, I get "No class def found" error! I have checked and confirmed gradle.build and made sure I have correct external jar (Client SDK). What can be the problem?

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath group: 'com.sun.identity', name: 'openam-clientsdk', version: '13.0.0'
    classpath group: 'com.iplanet.am', name: 'openam-clientsdk', version: '13.0.0'
}
}


dependencies {
     compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
compile group: 'org.forgerock.openam', name: 'openam-clientsdk', version: '13.0.0'
    runtime group: 'com.sun.identity', name: 'openam-clientsdk', version: '13.0.0'
    }
```

Here is the Kotlin code:

```
import com.iplanet.sso.SSOTokenManager
import com.iplanet.sso.SSOException
import com.iplanet.sso.SSOToken
import com.sun.identity.idm.IdConstants
import com.sun.identity.sm.*
import com.sun.identity.authentication.*
import com.sun.identity.authentication.spi.AuthLoginException
import com.sun.identity.authentication.share.AuthXMLTags
import java.util.*
import javax.security.auth.callback.*`

@Throws(SSOException::class, AuthLoginException::class, Exception::class)
fun realmLogin(userid: String, password: String, realm: String):SSOToken? {
    val mgr: SSOTokenManager
    val adminDN: String
    val adminPassword: String
    val ssoToken: SSOToken?
    val authType = AuthContext.IndexType.MODULE_INSTANCE
    val lc: AuthContext

try {
    lc = AuthContext(realm)
} catch (le: AuthLoginException) {
    System.err.println(
            "IdRepoSampleUtils: could not get AuthContext for realm " + realm)
    throw le
}

try {
    lc.login()
} catch (le: AuthLoginException) {
    System.err.println("IdRepoSampleUtils: Failed to start login " + "for default authmodule")
       throw le
   }

   var callbacks: Array<Callback>?
   val values = Hashtable<String, String>()
    values.put(AuthXMLTags.NAME_CALLBACK, userid)
    values.put(AuthXMLTags.PASSWORD_CALLBACK, password)

    while (lc.hasMoreRequirements()) {
        callbacks = lc.getRequirements()
        try {
            fillCallbacks(callbacks, values)
            lc.submitRequirements(callbacks)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            System.err.println("Failed to submit callbacks!")
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }

    }

    val istat = lc.getStatus()
    if (istat === AuthContext.Status.SUCCESS) {
        println("==>Authentication SUCCESSFUL for user " + userid)
    } else if (istat === AuthContext.Status.COMPLETED) {
        println("==>Authentication Status for user " +
            userid + " = " + istat)
        return null
    }

    try {
        ssoToken = lc.getSSOToken()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        System.err.println("Failed to get SSO token!  " + e.message)
        throw e
    }

     return ssoToken
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    realmLogin("amAdmin", "MyPassword", "")
}


    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/forgerock/guava/common/collect/ImmutableMap
at com.iplanet.am.util.SystemProperties.<clinit>(SystemProperties.java:121)
at com.sun.identity.configuration.FedSystemProperties.isServerMode(FedSystemProperties.java:115)
at com.sun.identity.configuration.FedSystemProperties.get(FedSystemProperties.java:90)
at com.sun.identity.shared.configuration.SystemPropertiesManager.get(SystemPropertiesManager.java:137)
at com.sun.identity.shared.debug.Debug.initialize(Debug.java:262)
at com.sun.identity.shared.debug.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:754)
at com.sun.identity.sm.SMSEntry.<clinit>(SMSEntry.java:96)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceManager.<clinit>(ServiceManager.java:78)
at com.sun.identity.sm.ServiceConfigManager.<init>(ServiceConfigManager.java:93)
at MainKt.main(Main.kt:145)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.forgerock.guava.common.collect.ImmutableMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more`
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please provide us more detailed information?

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA Edited the question text for full code and error

Comment: `org.forgerock.guava.common.collect.ImmutableMap` is included in forgerock-guava-collect-x.x.x.jar. You may have to add it to gradle dependencies.

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA Thanks! Fixed the error by copying jar file from installed openAM directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KoheiTAMURA mentioned, I fixed the error by adding required jar (forgerock-guava-collect-18.0.1.jar) from OpenAM installation folder to my project.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the ClientSDK in new applications. The ClientSDK is deprecated and isn't released in newer versions of OpenAM.

You should use the REST APIs with an http-client of your choice instead.

Comment: I surely know about REST, but there are tons of things impossible using REST. For example, changing new Realm settings. From the other side, I am using OpenAM 12 and some newer features are added to OpenAM 13.

Comment: The 13 ClientSDK versions are not really that stable, you are likely to hit other classpath related issues in my opinion. To overcome the REST API limitations, consider upgrading to a newer version of OpenAM.